# How do I change only one element's value in a Nested JSON in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin

Say I have a JSON like below...

```
{"cars": [ { "id": 1, "brand": "Honda", "milesDriven": "100,000"}, { 
"id": 2, "brand": "Toyota", "milesDriven" : "50,000"}, { "id": 3, 
"brand": "Kia", "milesDriven" : "25,000"} ]}

data class CarModel(val id: Int, val brand: String, var milesDriven: Int)
```

My initial car data is from a database GET. I need to send a copy of this data to a SecondActivity where I am going to POST it with the updated list to the database. For this I am using sharedPreferences to pass the initial list to the Second Activity where it is POSTed from:

```
// Send CarList to SecondActivity
val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", 
MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
val gson = Gson()
val json: String = gson.toJson(carList)
editor.putString("carList", json)
editor.apply()

// Receive CarList in Second Activity
val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", 
MODE_PRIVATE)
val carsJson = sharedPreferences.getString("cars", null)
// Parse JSON to ArrayList
val type: Type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<CarModel?>?>() {}.type
//val carsList = gson.fromJson<Any>(carsJson, type) as ArrayList<*>
changed->: val carsList: ArrayList<CarModel> = gson.fromJson(carJson, type)
val cars = gson.convertToJsonString(carsList)
println("cars: $cars")
```

I wanted to update milesDriven for only the Kia to "30,000" and then convert it back to a format I can POST to a database. How could I achieve this?

I tried cactustictacs's suggestion of:
cars.map { if (it.brand == "Kia") it.copy(milesDriven = 30_000) else it
}
but the println does not reflect a change in the milesDriven for Kia.

Comment: Are you using a JSON library to manipulate the objects in that structure? That would be easier (and less error-prone) than trying to mess with the string representation directly

Comment: What would you suggest using?

Comment: Like in jayesh's answer, you could use the JSON stuff in the standard library, or you could use something like GSON to convert it to your own data objects. JSON is fine for specific quick changes, but for more complex structures - and especially if you're actually going to be using the data in Kotlin itself - converting to data objects is usually a much better idea

Comment: Ok yeah, I am using GSON, I thought you may be referring to another library. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In that case, you're not actually working with the JSON data itself, right? So if your `Car` object is a data class, it's just a case of doing something like `cars.map { if (it.brand == "Kia") it.copy(milesDriven = 30_000) else it }` to update your list, or modify things directly if they're mutable. And then you can output it to a JSON string when you're done - the JSON itself isn't really relevant, you're just working with data objects and lists etc right?

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect more code. I have tried your solution but get unresolved references for "brand" and "copy". It probably has to do with how I am getting my data via sharedPreferences. I am new to JSON so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're deserialising to a `CarModel` data class (which gives you the `copy` function) with a `brand` property, maybe your problem is that you're casting your list to `ArrayList<*>` so the type system doesn't know what's in there? Can't you just call `val carsList = gson.fromJson(carsJson, type)`? (Or maybe `val carsList: ArrayList<CarModel?> = ...` if you have to) I haven't used Gson but that looks like the basic way you use it, since you're already specifying a `TypeToken` (also does `CarModel` need to be nullable in that list?)

Comment: I implemented "val carsList: ArrayList<CarModel?> = ..." and your previous suggestion and had no errors, which is great. However, when I got my println() the milesDriven had not been changed. Is there anything else I would need to code after your suggestion and before val carList = gson.convertToJsonString(carList) is called?

Comment: I messed around and I believed I figured it out using your suggestions. If you want credit please make it as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nah it's cool, I don't really have a formal solution to your problem - you just need to deserialise it to your objects, and then manipulate your list! You can use the `copy` method to make a new `Car` to replace the one in your list (which is what the `map` suggestion does - makes a new list with the old Kia item swapped out for your new one) or you can just find that item and change its `milesDriven` since you made that a `var`. The immutable (`val`) version with `copy` is usually preferable since it avoids bugs where data is changing, but depends what you need - keep it simple and all that!

Answer (score 2):

You can go either by JSONObject way (older and error chances are high) or some converter library like GSON

JSONObject way

```
val json = "{\"cars\": [ { \"id\": 1, \"brand\": \"Honda\", \"milesDriven\": \"100,000\"}, { \"id\": 2, \"brand\": \"Toyota\", \"milesDriven\" : \"50,000\"}, { \"id\": 3, \"brand\": \"Kia\", \"milesDriven\" : \"25,000\"} ]}"
        val jsonObject = JSONObject(json)

        val carsArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cars")
        loop@for(counter in 0 until carsArr.length()){
            val obj = carsArr.getJSONObject(counter)
            if(obj.getString("brand") == "Kia"){
                obj.put("milesDriven","30,000")
                carsArr.put(counter,obj)
                jsonObject.put("cars",carsArr)
                break@loop
            }
        }

        Log.e("json",jsonObject.toString())
```

Using GSON

```
val json = "{\"cars\": [ { \"id\": 1, \"brand\": \"Honda\", \"milesDriven\": \"100,000\"}, { \"id\": 2, \"brand\": \"Toyota\", \"milesDriven\" : \"50,000\"}, { \"id\": 3, \"brand\": \"Kia\", \"milesDriven\" : \"25,000\"} ]}"

        val item = Gson().fromJson<Item>(json,Item::class.java)
        val index = item.list.indexOfFirst {
            it.brand == "Kia"
        }
        item.list[index].milesDriven = "30,000"

        Log.e("json",Gson().toJson(item))
```

`Item` data class

```
data class Item(
    @SerializedName("cars")
    var list : MutableList<Car> = mutableListOf()
) {

    data class Car(
        @SerializedName("id")
        var id : String?=null,
        @SerializedName("brand")
        var brand : String?=null,
        @SerializedName("milesDriven")
        var milesDriven : String?=null,
    )
}
```

Dependecy
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'

https://github.com/google/gson

as per above code we can prefer using GSON library

Comment: Thank you for your time Jayesh. I have tried the above and am having some issues. I have updated my code in my question if you have time to aid in a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @DJTalls can you post your error also along with code that is storing into shared preference so we can know how and what you are storing in preference